# how to serialize json response to dictionary in alamofire 2 with swift 2 without swifty json

Tags: alamofire

This code used to work in the previousversion of alamofire before swift 2.  Now it gives a warning: `cast from Result<AnyObject> to Dictionary<String, AnyObject> always fails`.

```
  Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.POST, url, parameters:params)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data) -> Void in

            var result = data as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> //this gives an error cast from Result<AnyObject> to Dictionary<String, AnyObject> always fails
```

How can I get the cast to dictionary working?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to call:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters:params)
    .responseJSON { request, response, result in
        debugPrint(result)

        if let value = result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
           print(value)
        }
    }
```

You should read through the updated [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-serialization) code samples.

Comment: Saved my time , i was struggling to convert the response in dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bit too late to answer this but I share this because I feel like maybe this code can help someone:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
            {
                response in

                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                let data = response.result.value

                let responseObject = data as? NSDictionary

                switch (response.result)
            {
                case .success(_):

                print(responseObject!["message"] as! NSString as String)
                break

                case .failure(_):
                   SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: (responseObject!["message"] as! NSString as String))
                print(responseObject!["message"] as! NSString as String)
                break
            }
        }
```

Thanks and Enjoy! Happy coding! :)